# redirect to new page after login in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

I'm having some issue with redirecting to home page after user login / sign up-- hope someone can help.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    //create user if it doesn't exist
    const {
      setCurrentUser
    } = this.props;
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async(userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);

        userRef.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
          setCurrentUser({
            id: snapShot.id,
            ...snapShot.data(),
          });
        });
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(userAuth);
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = 'App' >
      <
      Router >
      <
      HeaderContainer >
      <
      Header / >
      <
      /HeaderContainer>

      <
      Routes >
      <
      Route element = { < ProtectedRoute / >
      } >
      <
      Route path = '/'
      element = { < HomePage / >
      }
      /> <
      /Route>

      <
      Route exact path = '/hello'
      element = { < LandingPage / >
      }
      />

      <
      Route exact path = '/signup'
      element = { < SignUp / >
      }
      /> { /* <Route exact path='/signin' element={<SignIn />} /> */ } <
      Route exact path = '/signin'
      render = {
        () =>
        this.props.currentUser ? < Navigate to = '/' / > : < SignIn / >
      }
      /> <
      /Routes> <
      /Router> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({
  user
}) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

I have this in my app JS-- where the proposed redirect shows a blank screen..

console:

```
Matched leaf route at location "/signin" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page. warning @ index.tsx:25
```

However, if I just rendered SignIn page as

```js
<Route exact path='/signin' element={<SignIn />} />
```

It runs fine without transitioning onto home screen from sign in page.. user has to manually

Comment: can you show the code of your SignUp/SignIn component, maybe the issue is there ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use router.push(‘/signin’) instead of redirecting inside a render (.   render = {
() =>
this.props.currentUser ? < Navigate to = '/' / > : < SignIn / >). It doesnt seem right

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the behavior you want by adding the **render** logic inside the **element** prop:

```
<Route path='/signin' element={this.props.currentUser ? <Navigate to='/'/> : <SignIn/>} />
```

You can check the React Router v6 changes on the [upgrading guideline](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) or [faq](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq).